# How can I fetch multiple lazy loaded OneToMany lists?

Tags: jpa, one-to-many

I have an Entity with multiple unidirectional OneToMany relationships like following.
How can I fetch all this fields in **one query**? 
What would be the best way if I have up to 10 Arraylists with a OneToMany relationship?

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "members")
public class Member extends Auditable<String> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    private Gender gender;

    private String lastName;

    private String firstName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private List<Phone> phoneList = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private List<EMail> eMailList = new ArrayList<>();

// more Lists with OneToMany relationship
}
```

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "emails")
public class EMail extends Auditable<String> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Long id;
    private Type type;
    private String value;
}
```

I tried following step in my MemberRepository class which is ending in a MultipleBagFetchException:

```
@Query("SELECT m " +
            "FROM Member m " +
            "LEFT JOIN FETCH m.eMailList " +
            "LEFT JOIN FETCH m.phoneList " +
            "WHERE m.memberId = ?1")
Optional<Member> findByMemberIdWithAllInfoQuery(Long id);   // MultipleBagFetchException
```

Then I tried following step with this information https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-multiplebagfetchexception/  which also doesn't work properly:

```
public Optional<Member> findMemberWithAllFieldsQuery(Long memberId) {

        Member _member = entityManager.createQuery(
                "SELECT DISTINCT m " +
                        "FROM Member m " +
                        "LEFT JOIN FETCH m.eMailList " +
                        "WHERE m.memberId = :id ", Member.class)
                .setParameter("id", memberId)
                .setHint(QueryHints.HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, false)
                .getSingleResult();

        _member = entityManager.createQuery(
                "SELECT DISTINCT m " +
                        "FROM Member m " +
                        "LEFT JOIN FETCH m.phoneList " +
                        "WHERE m in :member ", Member.class)
                .setParameter("member", _member)
                .setHint(QueryHints.HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, false)
                .getSingleResult();


        return Optional.of(_member);
    }
```

Thanks for your help/hints!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Set instead of List ? I've run into this exception and solved it after changing my collection to Set

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
private Set<Phone> phoneList = new HashSet<>();

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
private Set<EMail> eMailList = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the right way, but it saved me